# Can we use KStream with Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams, flink-streaming

I am using flink streams in a micro-service architecture to ETL data from services to reporting and search databases. To sense data changes, i am currently generating custom event to RMQ and then use streams to partition, aggregate and transform data based on reporting and search needs.

I am migrating to kafka as broker and debezium to get data, from all of the micro-services' databases. I am wandering if i may use KStreams API or flink  or there is any possibility to combine both.

Answer (score 2):

Since Kafka Streams can be embedded into any Java Application, in theory, the answer is yes.

However, for ETL purposes, there would be no need because Flink can already do the filter, map, aggregate operations between different Kafka topics and even different clusters (which Kafka Streams cannot do)

Comment: Standard operations such as map or filter, joins, and aggregations are examples of stream processors that are available in [Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/concepts.html#stream-processor) out of the box.

Comment: My question is either Kafka echo system is an ideal framework for such ETL or we have any option to use KStream with Flink that can provide additional benefit on top. 
And I may use most of my existing Flink implementation.

Comment: Yes, Standard operations are out of the box, but you how you deploy Kafka Streams is not a given like Flink. There is no cluster orchestrator. All I'm saying is that Flink has the same operations, and is more feature rich with external system support, so why try to integrate them if you aren't trying to use a KTable, for example